# What does G-d do on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, commentaries

Shabbat is a day of rest, but are there any commentaries that tell us what G-d is doing on this day? Does He also rest or is He involved in certain activities, duties, tasks, work?

Comment: I guess it makes sense to first ask what he does the rest of the time.

Comment: @msh210 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/115420/13438

Comment: It says that whatever God tells the Jews to do, he does himself. So it stands to reason that he "rests" on shabbos as well.